# Why using import BaseHTTPServer in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, webserver

This is the code I got from Tutorial of how to make local server by using python script to run in Terminal

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import os

HOSTNAME = "localhost"

PORT = 8000

HANDLER = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

os.chdir("/Users/Team/Desktop/python server")

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOSTNAME, PORT), HANDLER)


print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I wonder why they have to import the  BaseHTTPServer? can anyone explain me about that? below is the version from Python.org

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

You'll see that there is no import BaseHTTPServer, can anyone explain to me why?

and these code are in Python 2.7 if I want to change it into python 3 Do I still need to import BaseHTTPServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing it has has meaningful impact, as you have discovered. As for why it is there - who knows? Maybe the author of the tutorial intended to use it later in the tutorial, or maybe it was adapted from a larger sample. The point is if nothing is referencing it, you don't need to import it.

The same applies to python 3.

Comment: so without it my server will be fine right? there just be for some other purpose later on. Thank you very much ^^

Comment: If you are not using it, you'll be fine. Once/if you need it, you can just import it again.

Comment: That simply isn't true, I'm afraid. There are plenty of examples where importing something has a necessary side effect, for example registering a plugin class. You can't rely just on things not being referenced in your own code